# Why does my getter return a different value every time?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

I have the following class:

```
class Counter {

    constructor(start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    set start(number) {
        this._start = number;
    }

    get start() {
        return this._start++;
    }

    next() {
        return this.start + 1;
    }
}
```

I instantiate it as follows:

```
let counter = new Counter(23);
```

It works fine if I do my next function:

```
counter.next(); // 24
counter.next(); // 25
// ...
```

But if I log out `start` I always get something different

```
counter.start; // 25;
counter.start; // 26;
```

Why is this happening?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `this._start` or `this.start` ?

Comment: I don't think this is a realistic question. Users are unlikely to be encountering this specific situation except under contrived circumstances.

Comment: `this._start++` will increment `this._start` every time it's called.  Your code is doing what it is supposed to.  If you don't want to increment `this._start`, then don't use `++`.

Comment: Ahh but the next function works as expected @jfriend00

Comment: Sure, `next()` doesn't use `++` so it doesn't change `this.start`.

Comment: If I get rid of the ++ from the start getter then the next function does not work anymore @jfriend00

Comment: It is NOT clear at all what you want the behavior to be!  I'd suggest you back up and describe in words (in your question) exactly what the behavior of `start` and `next` is supposed to be.  And, explain why you have both `this.start` and `this._start`.  We can only help you if we know exactly what the behavior is SUPPOSED to be.

Comment: Start is a getter. Next should increment the counter and give you the next number in the sequence @jfriend00

Comment: So, why use `++` on `start`?  If it's JUST a getter - it should NOT change state.  Increment `this.start` on `next()`.  And, please explain why you have `this._start` AND `this.start`.  Confusing to us.

Comment: Sorry bad naming. The get/set should probably be called something like current count. @jfriend00

Comment: I still have zero idea why you have both `this._start` and `this.start` and what each is for.  Basically your question does not explain the goal of your design.  It describes an output that is not what you want, but doesn't describe what it is supposed to do.  It's not a good question at all.  Apparently you're fishing for votes by supplying an answer to your own bad question.  That would be fine if it was a good and clear question, but as it is now, it's of little use to the overall community because the question is so unclear. Please fix the question to describe how it is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is something wrong there.

The `Counter` class is accidentally mutating the object in the getter which was probably unintentional.

To fix that you can do:

```
class Counter {

    constructor(start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    set start(number) {
        this._start = number;
    }

    get start() { // always return the current start
        return this._start;
    }

    next() { // increase the start only in the next function!
        return ++this.start;
    }
}
```